# How to send avro events to esper using sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, avro, esper

I'm trying to send an avro event to esper using sockets.
I'm using the EsperIOSocketAdapter class described in [Esper-IO](http://esper.espertech.com/release-7.1.0/esperio-reference/html_single/index.html#adapter_socket), it works perfectly with POJO events and Map events, but I can't make it work with avro events.

**So basically I need to send an event represented by Avro to the Esper Socket Adapter.**

I'm using Esper 7.1.0

This is my Esper intialization, I'm using an event named "PersonEvent" with two fields, "name" of type String and "age" of type int:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
EPServiceProvider engine = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider(conf);

//event Avro
ConfigurationEventTypeAvro avroType = new ConfigurationEventTypeAvro();
Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse("{"+
    "\"type\": \"record\","+
    "\"name\": \"PersonEvent\","+
    "\"fields\":["+
    "{\"name\": \"name\", \"type\": \"string\"}," +
    "{\"name\": \"age\",  \"type\": \"int\"}" +
    "]" +
    "}");
avroType.setAvroSchema(schema);

engine.getEPAdministrator().
    getConfiguration().
    addEventTypeAvro("PersonEvent", avroType);
```

I also added a statement to watch esper incoming events:

```
String epl = "select name, age from PersonEvent";
EPStatement statement = engine.getEPAdministrator().createEPL(epl);

statement.addListener((newData, oldData) -> {
    String name = (String) newData[0].get("name");
    int age = (int) newData[0].get("age");
    System.out.println(String.format("Name: %s, Age: %d", name, age));
});
```

This is the Socket adapter initialization:

```
ConfigurationSocketAdapter adapterConfig = new ConfigurationSocketAdapter();
SocketConfig socket = new SocketConfig();
socket.setDataType(DataType.OBJECT);
socket.setPort(8085);
adapterConfig.getSockets().put("SocketService", socket);

EsperIOSocketAdapter socketAdapter = new EsperIOSocketAdapter(adapterConfig, "default");
socketAdapter.start();
```

Finally, to send the event to the socker I've tried several things:

First try (works fine with POJO events, but not for Avro):

```
Socket requestSocket = new Socket("localhost", 8085);
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(requestSocket.getOutputStream());
out.writeObject(new PersonEvent("John", 23));
out.flush();

out.close();
requestSocket.close();
```

Second try (works fine with Map events, but not for Avro):

```
Socket requestSocket = new Socket("localhost", 8085);
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(requestSocket.getOutputStream());
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map.put("stream","PersonEvent");
map.put("name","John");
map.put("age",10); 
out.writeObject(map);
out.flush();

out.close();
requestSocket.close();
```

Third try (found in internet but doesn't work):

```
Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse("{"+
    "\"type\": \"record\","+
    "\"name\": \"PersonEvent\","+
    "\"fields\":["+
    "{\"name\": \"name\", \"type\": \"string\"}," +
    "{\"name\": \"age\",  \"type\": \"int\"}" +
    "]" +
    "}");

//Here also tried with ObjectOutputStream, like first try
OutputStream outToServer = requestSocket.getOutputStream();
EncoderFactory enc=new EncoderFactory();
//Here I also tried with JsonEncoder
BinaryEncoder binaryEncoder=enc.binaryEncoder(outToServer,null);
DatumWriter datumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter(schema);

GenericData.Record event = new GenericData.Record(schema);
event.put("name", "Joshn");
event.put("age", 10);
datumWriter.write(event,binaryEncoder);
binaryEncoder.flush();
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the adapter takes avro. Your option is to change it or write your own.